# How can several branches be nested in the same directory in a bzr-builder recipe?

Tags: ppa, packaging, bazaar

I have the following recipe:

```
# bzr-builder format 0.3 deb-version 7.0+{revno}
lp:~bitglue/openobject-server/7.0
nest addons lp:~bitglue/openobject-addons/7.0 openerp/addons
nest-part web lp:~openerp/openerp-web/7.0 addons openerp/addons
```

The base openobject-server has an `openerp/addons` directory with some stuff in it. The other projects have more addons which I want to stuff in the same `openerp/addons` directory.

The problem is that as this is being built, a conflict on `openerp/addons` is generated. None of the subdirectories have the same name, so all these things could peacefully coexist.

I thought about `nest-part`ing the individual addons, but there are many, many addons in openobject-addons. It would be very tedious to list each one individually, plus I'd have to remember to touch the recipe when adding a new addon.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest multiple branches into the same directory.

However, the problem is that youa re nesting the directories wrong. You need to specify a unique name for a directory which doesn't yet exist, as the last argument to the nest or nest-part commands. Something like this should work, assuming the directories don't already exist:

```
nest addons lp:~bitglue/openobject-addons/7.0 openerp/addons/openobject-addons
nest-part web lp:~openerp/openerp-web/7.0 addons openerp/addons/openerp-web
```

Alternatively, as these are all separate sources, you should package them separately, rather than trying to shove them all into a single source branch, I think.

Comment: Poo. You are probably right, but I was hoping I could be lazy and avoid learning to package properly.

Comment: I had a thought that I could execute a command from the recipe to move/symlink some of the files into the addons directory, or that I could modify the packaging scripts to do the same. In the end though, I bit the bullet and built my own packages for the three components. The particular project in question, OpenERP, does somehow package everything together, but they don't seem to want to share their process.